# Hybrid Mobile app crashes on iOS 8.3

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk

It seems that using SmartStore causes the app to freeze when installing an app for the first time, then a hard reset of the device is required. After that, the app seems to work fine. I experienced this both on my production app and when testing on the SmartStore Explorer sample app. Loading a fresh install of the same app on to iOS 8.2 has no issues.

I believe it is related to SmartStore because I do not receive any console logs on soup registration success or error, which I do receive when testing my app in iOS 8.2.

forceios version: 3.1.1

iOS: 8.3 (freezes on fresh install of app)

iOS: 8.2 (works fine)

App Type: Both hybrid_remote and hybrid_local seem to have the same issues (my app is remote, SmartStore Explorer is local)

Device: Mostly using iPad, experienced the freezing issue on an iPhone with iOS 8.3 also﻿